# Firebase: How to reference a path in Firebase using a variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to reference a variable in my Firebase Realtime Database, but my console doesn't display the data that I want. The right uid is logged, however, I don't know how to reference the variable called serial.

```
componentDidMount() {
    const uid = this.state.user.uid;
    console.log(uid);
    const serial = db.ref(uid + "/serial");
    console.log(serial);
```

[Here is the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSzzK.png)

[Here is my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEvbt.png)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question you want to get the value of the `uid/serial` node.

By doing `const serial = db.ref(uid + "/serial");` you define a [`Reference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference). You need to query the data at this `Reference`, by using the `once()` or the `on()` methods.

For example:

```
const serialRef = db.ref(uid + "/serial");
serialRef.once('value')
  .then(function(dataSnapshot) {
    console.log(dataSnapshot.val());
  });
```

Note that the [`once()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once) method **is asynchronous** and returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) which resolves with a `DataSnapshot`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This sloved the problem.

Comment: Have also a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const uid = this.state.user.uid;
    console.log(uid);
    const dbItem = db.ref(uid);
    console.log(dbItem.serial);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply! Unfortunately this didn't solve the problem. Now it logs the uid and then for the second log it returns undefined.